# Getting related data via an AutoMapper mapping?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper, entity-framework-core

I want to create a mapping between this entity model:

```
public class ProductType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductIdentifierInType> Identifiers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductPropertyInType> Properties { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

... and this viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModelProductType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public IList<ViewModelProductIdentifier> Identifiers { get; set; }
    public IList<ViewModelProductProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; }
}
```

... but since the `Identifiers` and `Properties` are not of the same type in the viewmodel as in the entity model, it won't work directly, like this:

```
CreateMap<ProductType, ViewModelProductType>();
```

I don't want to change my models too much. In the entity model, I need the `Identifiers` and `Properties` to be respectively `ProductIdentifierInType` and `ProductPropertyInType`, because there are many-to-many relationships there, which requires linking tables.

But in the viewmodel, I need `Identifiers` and `Properties` to be the full objects in order to display their properties in the view.

Is there a way to accomplish this with mapping? Maybe using `.ForPath()` to get the two objects' properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have defined the direct entity to view model mappings:

```
CreateMap<ProductIdentifier, ViewModelProductIdentifier>();
CreateMap<ProductProperty, ViewModelProductProperty>();
```

Now it would be enough to extract the corresponding member using LINQ `Select` inside `MapFrom` expression. The important thing to know is that AutoMapper does not require the type of the returned expression to match the type of the destination. If they don't match, AutoMapper will use the explicit or implicit mappings for that types.

```
CreateMap<ProductType, ViewModelProductType>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Identifiers, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
        src.Identifiers.Select(link => link.Identifier)))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Properties, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
        src.Properties.Select(link => link.Property)))
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a [Custom Value Resolver](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html).
There you can explicitly specify how Auto Mapper should map one object to another.

In your case it could look something like this:

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<ProductType, ViewModelProductType, IList<ViewModelProductIdentifier>>
{
    public int Resolve(ProductType source, ViewModelProductType destination, IList<ViewModelProductIdentifier> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // Map you source collection to the destination list here and return it
    }
}
```

You can then pass/inject the resolver when calling CreateMap, i.e.:

```
CreateMap<ProductType, ViewModelProductType>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Identifiers, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
```

Analogously, do the same for your 'Properties' property.
Note that I did not debug this but merely adapted the examples provided in the link above.